# Intermittent Processor Lock / System Hang

Tags: ubuntu, cpu, freeze, logging

I have an Ubuntu 8.04 LTS Server that we use as a web server.  It's a standard LAMP stack and our site is set up in Drupal.  This seems to work without a problem for weeks on end.  Then, out of nowhere, the processor will lock up entirely.  When it does the only choice I seem to have is to hard-reset the system.

Remote logins all become unavailable, and if I sit in front of the terminal I'm sometimes able to type in my username, but it never gets as far as asking me for the password.  Because I can't get into the system I can't seem to isolate the process that's consuming all of the processor time.  I'm wondering what logs I can review or what I can enable to get access to better information and track down a root cause.  Ideally, if I can find out what's causing the problem I can prevent it from recurring.

Comment: So is the CPU actually hard-locking, or is it just so busy that the system becomes unresponsive?

Comment: @techie007 - Probably just so busy I can't get anything in edge-wise.  The machine appears to be running still, but entirely unresponsive.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [log files](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-gnome-system-log-viewer/), install [munin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Munin_%28network_monitoring_application%29), monitor the system and clean/check the computer physically (there are some videos on [youtube](http://youtu.be/Y2gi0GTzfTA) about how-to clean the cpu and the heatsink).

good luck!